# The Dispute at the Milky Way Restaurant

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, word-search

Fifteen related guests visited a restaurant and got into an argument about who was the greatest among them. To settle the dispute, they asked the owner to decide.
He thought for a moment, then said “While you are eating, write down as many stars as you can name. After the meal I will tally the results.”
The guests finished their meal in peace, then handed in their work.
“So who is the greatest?” asked one.
“I dare not say; I fear another brawl. But I will send you each home with a word search puzzle.  The one I chose is encoded within. And it’s not the one who named the most stars. That was a ploy to keep you occupied while you ate. To ensure you are far apart by the time you decode this, I have obfuscated your names. Tiny ladle may have named the most stars, but they are not necessarily the one I deem the greatest!”
“But there are only fifteen of us,” retorted one.
“Yes, to get you started, I added the name of my restaurant into the mix and highlighted it for you. See? ‘A star queue banded overhead’? That’s this restaurant, the Milky Way. As you can see, this is not a normal word search.”
“It’s jagged. But the letters are connected, right? Without doubling back on themselves or anything sneaky like that?”
“Certainly.”
“And you promise this reveals who you deem the greatest?”
“Yes, you all are hidden within. But once solved, one of you will stand out!”

Here is the list of participants the owner wrote down:

1 thousand stars – “Peace age sunshine dawns” (8)
2 thousand stars – “A star queue banded overhead” (8)
3 thousand stars – “Is thunderbolt carrier of Zeus” (6)
5 thousand stars – “Is a worthy foe on Hercules’ first labor” (3)
6 thousand stars – “The quick bunny hunter” (10)
7 thousand stars – “Vain queen is banished skyward” (10)
8 thousand stars – “Stings cause massive pain” (8)
10 thousand stars – “Is Orpheus’ extraordinary instrument” (4)
11 thousand stars – “These begin in May, exit June” (6)
12 thousand stars – “Sported golden fleece, once” (5)
14 thousand stars – “Bears a big copper pot on its back” (9)
15 thousand stars – “Hideous Typhon’s aquatic prey” (6)
18 thousand stars – “Mad Ford auto leaping with horn” (6)
19 thousand stars – “Dons stars as a girdle and bow” (5)
20 thousand stars – “Bird crossing up north” (6)
21 thousand stars – “A tiny dipper atop Claus’ home” (9)

Here is the word search the owner created:

[image: word search]

Text Version ('MILKY WAY' is highlighted in a jagged line)

```
MCEFAZSAUYJOCSLKYEPTURAB    
IEURISTQRAUQIJTIONIMRGEM  
NYRYJVEOUAAUFSYWIPRTTORI  
AWRGJIKORGINIULFEINMYSCY  
IUGCEXUQCNOVMBILMWLKPWAG  
OXLYTNEIAPISCESWORDEGGAJ
```

Who was deemed the greatest and how do you know?

Hint:

> If the guests are not in the *traditional* word search, what is?

Hint 2:

> There are a few things in this puzzle which seem suspicious, unexpected, or unpleasing. Might they have a shared explanation? It can either be found directly or deduced. (If you find it, you could comment 'aha' and I'll stop giving hints to give you time to work the final stage).

Hint 3:

> What do the star counts and clues look like?

Hint 4:

> MJR

Hint 5:

> MJR (3 words of instruction) are trivial to find, essentially in plain sight, so I'm running out of hints as to how to find them. Regarding the clues, the star counts and text is critical. For example, changing 'vain queen' to 'conceited lady' makes the puzzle unsolvable.

Hint 6:

> MJR is found! Congrats @Elpharya! Now, what is "it"? Not what you probably think. Consider the entropy of this puzzle.

Hint 7:

> MJR was just an optional hint (not critical to the solution), so it was intentionally quite easy to find. Now we get to the crux of the puzzle. Can you find a single, logical mechanism which rectifies various problematic/unsatisfactory aspects of this puzzle and also makes the word search solvable? You can use MJR as a guide, or search this puzzle as a whole for additional hints/observations.

Hint 8:

> "This is not a normal word search."
>  "It's jagged."
>  Why did the guest say the puzzle was jagged? They were not referring to the 'Milky Way'. Think for example software programming or an old rug.

Hint 9:

> Why are there gaps in the star counts? What goes in the gaps?

Hint 10:

> Here is the top image search result I got for "merge jagged rows". Hopefully it will help?  https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200131134104/Jagged-Array.jpg  (think of a solution that is simple, almost trivial, yet not immediately obvious)

Hint 11:

> You stop at Scorpius' resort villa for a visit, and find the following scrap of paper lying outside their door.  "Interesting," you muse, pocketing it.
>  [image: clue]

Comment: Are you sure it's 15, not 12? I have an answer for twelve, it's The One Who Serves, referencing Jesus's sayings in The Bible *smirks*

Comment: Sounds like you know What is an Uncommon Word

Comment: Are the number of stars seen by each important to the wordsearch?

Comment: Also - will the letters in each word be sequential, or scrambled? for instance, if the l and the k in milky way was swapped, would it still be valid?

Comment: I see your point, no not scrambled, they will look just like the highlighted example or the other one that is rather conspicuous.

Comment: re: Hint 3 - it seems rot13(vg ybbxf yvxr pebffjbeq pyhrf, ohg gurer'f ab vaqvpngvba sbe npebff if qbja. V'z fgvyy hapyrne nf gb ubj vg yvaxf gb gur jbeqfrnepu, jurer 'zvyxl jnl' vf pyrneyl fubja.)

Comment: I suspect the poorly worded/uninspiring clues and dense numbering would make a very unsatisfying crossword.

Comment: Agreed. I'm stuck on how/why some guests aren't able to be found, where some are easily seen (milky way eg).

Comment: Probably because the guests are not what to look for, or at least if you're looking for a hint

Comment: Rot13 (Zl svefg gubhtug jura ybbxvat ng gur pyhrf vf gung gurl’er pelcgvp pyhrf nf jryy nf abezny pyhrf, nf V frr znal jbeqf gung pbhyq or vaqvpngbef be ovgf naq cvrprf, ohg V unira’g orra noyr gb fbyir nal fb sne. Gurer vf cebonoyl fbzr bgure cebcregl bs gur pyhrf gung znxrf gur jrveq jbeqvat znxr frafr, ohg V qba’g xabj jung gung zvtug or. Nyy gur pyhrf ner cerggl fvzvyne va yratgu naq jbeq pbhag, fb gung zvtug zrna fbzrguvat nf jryy.)

Comment: @SeptaCube you are very close

Comment: Maybe don't overthink the puzzle. No riddles, no ciphers, no programming. Everything you need is essentially in plain sight. Recall we are looking for JR to M.

Comment: Since little progress seems to be being made, some half-formed thoughts. rot13(1. Creuncf gur pyhrf gurzfryirf cebivqr gur yrggref sbe gur erny jbeqfrnepu. 2. Abg ol gnxvat A yrggref sebz gur pyhr ynoryyrq "A gubhfnaq", orpnhfr #20 unf bayl 19 yrggref. 3. Znlor ol bssfrggvat rnpu A fcnprf evtugjneq, ohg V ybbxrq ng gung naq vg qvqa'g frrz gb jbex. 4. "N fgne dhrhr" vf na vagrerfgvat ghea bs cuenfr. Gur N* tencu-frnepu nytbevguz hfrf n cevbevgl dhrhr; bar snapl vzcyrzragngvba bs guvf qngn fgehpgher vf n _Svobanppv urnc_ naq gur jbeqfrnepu unf 144 yrggref; 144 vf n Svobanppv ahzore.)

Comment: rot13(5. Nygreangviryl, creuncf jr ner zrnag gb gnxr gur yrggref bs gur jbeq frnepu naq erneenatr gurz fbzrubj, ohg V qba'g frr n cynhfvoyr jnl gb qb gung. "Wnttrq" va pbzchgvat (frr uvag) zrnaf n xvaq bs neenl gung pna unir ebjf bs qvssrerag yratguf, juvpu vf jul r.t. gnxvat A yrggref sebz gur pyhr ynoryyrq "A gubhfnaq" jnf n guvat gb pbafvqre, ohg gurer qbrfa'g frrz gb or nal pnabavpny jnl bs trggvat qvssrerag-yratgu ebjf sebz gur jbeq frnepu. Gur Svobanppv guvat vfa'g boivbhfyl urycshy; r.t., 1+2+...+89 vf hasbeghangryl 143, bar fubeg.)

Comment: rot13(6. Gur fhz bs bar, gjb, guerr, svir, fvk, ..., gjraglbar vf 172 = 2k2k43 juvpu jbhyqa'g sbez n avpr erpgnatyr, fb vs jr ner trggvat "wnttrq ebjf" bs gubfr yratguf vg qbrfa'g frrz yvxr jr'er zrnag gb "zretr" gurz vagb n fvatyr erpgnatyr.)

Comment: rot13(7. V nterr gung gur pyhrf ybbx n yvggyr nf vs gurl zvtug or pelcgvp pyhrf, ohg V gbb pna'g fbyir nal bs gurz vs fb; zber yvxryl vf gung gurl ybbx gung jnl orpnhfr gurl jrer jevggra haqre n pbafgenvag -- fhpu nf arrqvat gb sbez n jbeqfrnepu tevq be _fbzrguvat_. Vs gurl npghnyyl sbez gur erdhverq jbeqfrnepu fbzrubj, V nz vzcerffrq gung gurl qba'g ybbx zhpu jbefr guna gurl qb, rfcrpvnyyl nf gurl nyfb arrqrq gb pyhr tvira jbeqf. Creuncf gurl sbez bayl cneg bs gur jbeqfrnepu, naq gurer vf zber gb qb jvgu gur bevtvany tevq. Be creuncf guvf vfa'g ernyyl n jbeqfrnepu ng nyy.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan is converging upon the answer.  Occam may be helpful in filtering through the suggestions. Or do another image search for Queue.

Comment: rot13(Gurer ner "tncf" ng sbhe, avar, guvegrra, fvkgrra naq friragrra gubhfnaq fgnef. Yrg'f gnxr bayl gurfr pbyhzaf sebz gur bevtvany jbeq frnepu.) Oh, no, that can't be right ... `:)`

Comment: Aha! I think I've got i

Answer (score 12, accepted):

And it all becomes clear....

> Looking at the most recent Hint 11, with what looks like a torn off wordsearch... but wait? The last line looks the same, but the ones above don't? actually they look familiar - 'a tiny d', 'bird'... They're the clues!
>  So looking at the gaps, there's no clues for 4, 9, 16 and 17. So if we line up the hints as if they're in the wordsearch verbatim, and substituting the first line of the original wordsearch so it's now Row 4, and so on, we get a jagged wordsearch!
>  [image: word-search]

> so this looks like something we can work with! We have enough of a picture that we can see a figure become clear - the constellation for Orion - apparently the greatest of the constellations. But what about Scorpius's note? Zeus (who doesn't seem to have a constellation himself) is the owner of the Milky Way restaurant and the creator of the puzzle :)

> [image: coloured word-search]

> [image: constellation]

--clues--

1 thousand stars – “Peace age sunshine dawns” (8)

> AQUARIUS

2 thousand stars – “A star queue banded overhead” (8)

> Milky way - given in the question

3 thousand stars – “Is thunderbolt carrier of Zeus” (6)

> AQUILA - provided by @El-Guest, represents the bird that carries Zeus's bolts

5 thousand stars – “Is a worthy foe on Hercules’ first labor” (3)

> LEO - the first labor of Hercules is the slaying of the Nemean lion

6 thousand stars – “The quick bunny hunter” (10)

> CANIS MAJOR/MINOR - provided by @xhienne, which is a dog

7 thousand stars – “Vain queen is banished skyward” (10)

> CASSIOPEIA - a queen in greek mythology known for being vain

8 thousand stars – “Stings cause massive pain” (8)

> SCORPIUS - scorpions have stingers

10 thousand stars – “Is Orpheus’ extraordinary instrument” (4)

> LYRA - like a lyre

11 thousand stars – “These begin in May, exit June” (6)

> GEMINI - zodiac sign for those born between date in may and june

12 thousand stars – “Sported golden fleece, once” (5)

> ARIES - aka the ram

14 thousand stars – “Bears a big copper pot on its back” (9)

> URSA MAJOR - punny with bear, and the copper pot referring to the big dipper

15 thousand stars – “Hideous Typhon’s aquatic prey” (6)

> PISCES - a fish. Also visible on the last line of the wordsearch

18 thousand stars – “Mad Ford auto leaping with horn” (6)

> TAURUS - the bull, also available as a Ford Taurus

19 thousand stars – “Dons stars as a girdle and bow” (5)

> ORION - also known as the archer

20 thousand stars – “Bird crossing up north” (6)

> CYGNUS - a constellation that appears as a bird

21 thousand stars – “A tiny dipper atop Claus’ home” (9)

> URSA MINOR - the little dipper, appearing north (over Santa Claus' home)

Comment: Amazing! rot13(Whcvgre) is probably wrong: it is not a six-letter word and it is neither a star nor a constellation.

Comment: @xhienne thanks! You're totally right, I couldn't count for that one ha. I think with the new hint something else is missing in order to find the words in the search...

Comment: I was not able to find any name you found other than rot13(CVFPRF) in the word search. FOr “Is thunderbolt carrier of Zeus”, I initially thought it referred to the rot13(plpybcrf jub oebhtug gur guhaqreobyg gb Mrhf) but I wasn't able to match any of their names to a celestial body. For “The quick bunny hunter”, I think this is rot13(rvgure PNAVF ZVABE be PNAVF ZNWBE).

Comment: Good points... that would make sense for the "bunny hunter. I was almost thinking of looking for rot13(avpxanzrf sbe gur pbafryyngvbaf) instead, like rot13(YRB vf Yvba, juvpu V sbhaq va gbc/frpbaq ebj). I've found these ones in the search thinking about rot13(gjva sbe TRZVAV, enz sbe NEVRF, orne sbe HEFN ZNWBE, naq ohyy sbe GNHEHF)

Comment: @Elpharya I believe [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquila_(constellation)) is your missing six-letter thunderbolt carrier — you should now have all of the names at least!!

Comment: @El-Guest Thank you my El-friend! I'll add it in :)

Comment: @Elpharya The given wordsearch is perfectly normal (and quite easy) so it doesn't contain lion, bear, or any guest but Pisces. It contains ox but only by coincidence as it is short. It also contains your instructions.

Comment: Technically I forgot to mention not to use same letter twice... can you find a better Taurus? Once all are found, it's just a question of who stands out, which I think you already know : )

Comment: @Amoz Ah funny that it popped up twice. There was another instance of overlap between majOR and ORION - should I look for another one?

Comment: I mean the  different guests can overlap like any word search, but you used the same U twice for Taurus itself I think. Taurus has 2 U's so they should be different U's.

Comment: @Amoz There is a U (I highlighted it wrong), but this placement works. This was fun to solve (once I finally understood which direction to go ha)

Comment: @Elpharya Looks like a small gap where Leo goes (I'm not spotting any other highlighted Leo), but yep, excellent work! I updated the original puzzle to clarify that say Taurus would require 2 different U's within the connection instead of using  the same U; your fix is perfect!